# Yellowish turnip

Tags: vegetables

I got a turnip recently and it was a little yellowish and after cooking it was the same, a little yellowish and mushy.

A couple of months ago I got a turnip and it was white and after cooking it was translucent and firm, which is what I would expect.

Is this a seasonal thing where the spring turnips are white and firm, but then during the summer they get yellowish and mushy? Or did I just get a bad turnip?

Answer (score 6):

It appears that your first turnip was a "white turnip" - *Brassica rapa* - and your second was a rutabaga (Swede or yellow turnip) - *Brassica napobrassica*.

I found a brief list of differences [here](http://www.diffen.com/difference/Rutabaga_vs_Turnip).

Answer (score 1):

Turnip, radish,rutabaga. Same family. Can go to black to white in color. Spanish turnip would be black. Over winter turnips can be slightly soft. We use to leave fall turnips in the ground. Cover with straw. Dig up as needed in the winter. We found the black Spanish turnip best for this.